# AES encryption for Android/Java and .Net only partially identical

Tags: c#, java, android, vb.net, encryption

I am working on encrypting (and later decrypting) strings in .Net and Java (on Android), using AES encryption with a password and an initialization vector. I got the respective en- and decryption on each side individually running well, but I keep getting different results in comparison, thus not allowing to encrypt on one and decrypt on the other system. I especially dont get why the first half of the encrypted byte-Array is identical, while the second half differs (while all the other byte-arrays are totally identical)?

Here is what I get as byte-arrays from the two encryption codes I use:

Java (for easy comparison added +256 on values which have been negative):[**202, 147, 148, 168, 9, 104, 213, 176, 174, 157, 124, 160, 54, 33, 151, 246**, *70, 63, 184, 118, 228, 50, 242, 224, 231, 37, 34, 16, 123, 9, 143, 81*]

.Net:[**202, 147, 148, 168, 9, 104, 213, 176, 174, 157, 124, 160, 54, 33, 151, 246**, *109, 127, 84, 129, 168, 106, 21, 159, 131, 67, 75, 209, 166, 221, 190, 243*]

I post the two code fragments I use for encryption below. Although I am looking for a hint on what I do wrong for several hours now, I can't figure out where I'm wrong. Would be very kind if someone could point me on what I don't see...

Here is what I get when I print out all relevant values from both code versions:

```
Android-Output:
    Key (String): 6543210987654321
    IV (String): 1234567890123456
    Input (String): Encrypt_this_text

    Key (Bytes): [54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49]
    IV (Bytes): [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
    Input (Bytes): [69, 110, 99, 114, 121, 112, 116, 95, 116, 104, 105, 115, 95, 116, 101, 120, 116]

    Encrypted: [-54, -109, -108, -88, 9, 104, -43, -80, -82, -99, 124, -96, 54, 33, -105, -10, 70, 63, -72, 118, -28, 50, -14, -32, -25, 37, 34, 16, 123, 9, -113, 81]
    Encrypted (+256 if <0): [202, 147, 148, 168, 9, 104, 213, 176, 174, 157, 124, 160, 54, 33, 151, 246, 70, 63, 184, 118, 228, 50, 242, 224, 231, 37, 34, 16, 123, 9, 143, 81]

VBNet-Output:
    Key (String)=6543210987654321
    IV (String)=1234567890123456
    Input (String)=Encrypt_this_text

    Key (Byte)=[54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49]
    IV (Byte)=[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
    Input (Byte)=[69, 110, 99, 114, 121, 112, 116, 95, 116, 104, 105, 115, 95, 116, 101, 120, 116]

    Encrypted=[202, 147, 148, 168, 9, 104, 213, 176, 174, 157, 124, 160, 54, 33, 151, 246, 109, 127, 84, 129, 168, 106, 21, 159, 131, 67, 75, 209, 166, 221, 190, 243]
```

This is the java-code used for generating the encrypted byte-array:

```
String skey = "6543210987654321";
String siv = "1234567890123456";
String sinput = "Encrypt_this_text";

byte[] key = skey.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] iv = siv.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] input = sinput.getBytes("UTF8");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding");
SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES" );
IvParameterSpec ivparams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivparams);

byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input);
```

...and here's my Net (in this case VB) Testcode:

```
Dim rm As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged

Dim skey As String = "6543210987654321"
Dim siv As String = "1234567890123456"
Dim sinput As String = "Encrypt_this_text"

Dim key() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey)
Dim IV() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(siv)
Dim input() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sinput)

Dim ict As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, IV)

Dim encrypted() As Byte = ict.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length)
```

Comment: Notes: 1) Using ASCII encoding for the plaintext silently corrupts foreign characters. Use UTF-8 instead. 2) IV and key shouldn't use ASCII (or UTF-8). They're random binary values, so if you have to convert them to text, use Hex or Base64. 3) You must generate a new random IV for each message 4) To resist active attacks, you need to apply a MAC. Use an Encrypt-then-MAC scheme. make sure to include the whole ciphertext, including IV in the MAC. And use a constant time comparison for the MAC verification. Alternatively you can go for an authenticated mode like GCM instead of writing it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default padding in .NET's AesManaged.CreateEncryptor being PKCS7.

In Java, you initialize with Zeros padding.

You can override the padding by changing the Padding property in `rm` to `PaddingMode.Zeros`.

The relevant MSDN article : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.padding.aspx).

Comment: I'd do it the other way round, changing both to PKCS7. You can't remove `Zeros` padding, unless you know that the message does not end with a zero byte.

Comment: Thank you, never would have got that on my own: I thought I had read somewhere that the Net-standard was Zero padding by default, that's why I had used Zero padding in java on purpose... So, of course it works with your hint (adding rm.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.Zeros in VBNet), as the other way around by using Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING"); in Java.

Comment: I second CodesInChaos' comment - PKCS7 is better for most purposes.